# Django request.COOKIES returning empty dictionary

Tags: python, django, cookies, django-views

I've set some cookies using javascript `document.cookie = ...` and then am trying to retrieve them in a Django (1.8) view using `request.COOKIES`. However, when I print the result to the console it is just an empty dictionary.

I wrote this code a few weeks ago, and am pretty sure it was working then, but now I've come back to it broken. Cookies are visible in the Application window of the browser console and I can retrieve them using Javascript, just not Django.

I've read the docs and experimented with changing my settings, but can't see anything that makes much of a difference. Any suggestions of where I should look next would be appreciated.

I haven't provided any code because I have no idea where the problem is, and my app isn't tiny. Just looking for an avenue to explore as to why `request.COOKIES` isn't returning anything.

Thanks

EDIT 2:
This is only happening on Chrome. Safari is returning cookies as intended.

EDIT 1:
JavaScript function to set cookies:

```
function setcookie(cookieName,cookieValue) {
    var today = new Date();
    var expire = new Date();
    expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*14);
    document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString() + "; path=/";
}
```

Implemented like this:

`setcookie('areaMain', 'map)`

Cookie in tab:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP3me.png

Then attempting to see them in the view:

```
def index(request):
    cookies = request.COOKIES
    print(cookies)
```

returns `{}`

Comment: does you fron and back has the same port? Can you add some more code in your question?

Comment: I haven't changed the ports anywhere, so I assume they're the same if they're the same by default. My page is rendering as it should, I just can't retrieve the cookies.

Answer (score 1):

can you add in you view code like this:

```
def view(request):
    response = HttpResponse("hello")
    response.set_cookie('name', 'jujule')
    return response
```

And look is new cookie set?

Comment: Yep that works, cookie is set. But if I try to print it by again setting `print(request.COOKIES)` I get an empty dictionary again...

Comment: l will try some cases on my local machine and then write you, tomorrow.

Comment: Hello @BrownBear, I know this question is from 4 years ago. But I'm having the exact same problem and I haven't been able to discovered what is going on. Do you know what could be causing the `resquest.COOKIES` returning an empty object? I'm trying to set up Google Optimize in my project and I need one cookie set by Google for conditional rendering a view, but on first load I always get an empty cookies object.

Comment: if you set the cookies by javascript when you first time open the page, back-end can't see it because the cookies doesn't exists at the moment.